# Sql query to fetch minimum date start against each employee

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have two table `asg` and `work rship`

In work rship table there is `date_start` for each employee. For few employee date_start is duplicate so I have to choose the `min(date_start)` from work rship table

for this i wrote a query:

```
SELECT assignment_name,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(ASSIGNMENT_NAME, '[0-9]+') PERSON_NUMBER,
  NVL( wrk.date_start,t.effective_start_date) ,
  NVL( WRK.WORKER_TYPE,'E'),
  NVL( WRK.LEGAL_EMPLOYER_NAME, 'N/A')
FROM
  (SELECT apps.assignment_table.*,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY assignment_name, effective_start_date, effective_end_date, effective_latest_change) AS c
  FROM apps.assignment_table
  ) T
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT *
  FROM apps.work_table
  WHERE date_start =
    (SELECT MIN(date_start) FROM apps.work_table
    )
  ) wrk
ON regexp_substr(t.assignment_name, '[0-9]+')=wrk.person_number
WHERE C   =1;
```

But in the above query I did a mistake of just selecting select min(date_start) from apps.work_table this means min(date_start) from the entire table.
Instead of this I should have included the `regexp_substr(t.assignment_name, '[0-9]+')=wrk.person_number` inside the inline query itself.

But now when I am including it.. it's not working.

Comment: Why not just select personnumber,min(date_start) ... from TABLE1 JOIN table2?

Comment: will have to use group by.. have to fetch 13 columns from above query... this seemed better

Comment: Thats not, you are selecting twice from work table and once with analytic function on assignment table.

Comment: didnt get your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT *
  FROM apps.work_table
  WHERE date_start =
    (SELECT MIN(date_start) FROM apps.work_table
    )
  ) wrk
ON
```

Unless the `start_date` for the person is the minimum value across all people in the entire table (and not just the minimum date for this person) then the code above will not find any rows that will match the person you want.

What you probably meant to do is something like:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY person_number ORDER BY date_start ASC ) AS rn
    FROM   apps.work_table t
  )
  WHERE  rn = 1
) wrk
ON
```